# Best data structure for caching objects with a composite unique id

Tags: c#, caching, data-structures

I have a slow function that makes an expensive trip to the server to retrieve RecordHdr objects.  These objects are sorted by rid first and then by aid.  They are then returned in batches of 5.

```
    | rid | aid |
    -------------->
    | 1   | 1   | >
    | 1   | 3   | >  
    | 1   | 5   | > BATCH of 5 returned
    | 1   | 6   | >  
    | 2   | 2   | >
    -------------->
    | 2   | 3   |
    | 2   | 4   |
    | 3   | 1   |
    | 3   | 2   |
    | 3   | 5   |
    | 3   | 6   |
    | 4   | 1   |
    | 4   | 2   |
    | 4   | 5   |
    | 4   | 6   |
```

After I retrieve the objects, I have to wrap them in another class called WrappedRecordHdr.  **I'm wondering what is the best data structure I can use to maintain a cache of WrappedRecordHdr objects such that if I'm asked for an object by rid and aid, I return a particular object for it.  Also if I'm asked for the rid, I should return all objects that have that rid.**

So far I have created two structures for each scenario (This may not be the best way, but It's what I'm using for now):

```
    // key: (rid, aid)
    private CacheMap<int, int, WrappedRecordHdr> m_ridAidCache =
        new CacheMap<int, int, WrappedRecordHdr>();

    // key: (rid)
    private CacheMap<int, WrappedRecordHdr[]> m_ridCache =
        new CacheMap<int, WrappedRecordHdr[]>();
```

**Also, I'm wondering if there is a way I can rewrite this to be more efficient.**  Right now I have to get a number of records that I need to wrap within another object.  Then, I need to group them in a dictionary by id so that if I am asked for a certain rid I can return all objects that have the same rid.  The records have been already sorted, so I'm hoping the GroupBy doesn't attempt to sort them beforehand.

```
    RecordHdr[] records = server.GetRecordHdrs(sessId, BATCH_SIZE) // expensive call to server.

    // After all RecordHdr objects are retrieved, we loop through the received objects. For each RecordHdr object a WrappedRecordHdr object has to be created.
    WrappedRecordHdr[] wrappedRecords = new WrappedRecordHdr[records.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < wrappedRecords.Length; i++)
    {
        if (records[i] == null || records[i].aid == 0 || records[i].rid == 0) continue; // skip invalid results.

        wrappedRecords[i] = new WrappedRecordHdr(AccessorManager, records[i], projectId);
    }

    // Group all records found in a dictionary of rid => array of WrappedRecordHdrs, so all records with the same 
    // rid are returned.
    objects associated to a particular rid.
    Dictionary<int, WrappedRecordHdr[]> dict = wrappedRecords.GroupBy(obj => obj.rid).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToArray());

    m_ridCache = dict;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the data structure, I think there are really two different questions here:

1. What structure to use;
2. Should there be one or two caches;

It seems to me that you want one cache, typed as a [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx). The key would be the RID, and the value would be a Dictionary, where the key is an AID and the value is the header.

This has the following advantages:

1. The WrappedRecordHdrs are stored only once;
2. The MemoryCache already has all of the caching logic implemented, so you don't need to rewrite that;
3. When provided with only an RID, you know the AID of each WrappedRecordHdr (which you don't get with the array in the initial post);

These things are always compromises, so this has disadvantages too of course:

1. Cache access (get or set) requires constructing a string each time;
2. RID + AID lookups require indexing twice (as opposed to writing some fast hashing function that takes an RID and AID and returns a single key into the cache, however that would require that you either have two caches (one RID only, one RID + AID) or that you store the same WrappedRecordHdr twice per AID (once for RID + AID and once for null + AID));